# How do i create this many-to-one mapping using JPA?

Tags: jpa

I'd like to achieve the following schema:

> **Table A:** 
>   `a_id` 
>   (other columns)

---

> **Table B:**
>   `b_id`
>   (other columns)

---

> **Table C:**
>   `c_id`
>   (other columns)

---

> **Table D:**
>   `a_id_fk`
>   `b_id_fk`
>   `c_id_fk`

I would like to know how to create entity D. All the keys `a_id_fk`, `b_id_fk` and `c_id_fk` in Table D form a composite primary key.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It models a ternary association. In order to use it you need a map. JPA 1.0 does not support Map so if you want to use you need Hibernate because its Map suppport. It is something like

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @ManyToMany
    @org.hibernate.annotations.MapKeyManyToMany(
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="B_ID")
    )
    @JoinTable(
        name="D",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="A_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="C_ID")
    )
    private Map<B, C> bAndC = new HashMap<B, C>();

}
```

Notice each key is a B and each value is a C entity. In practice, it binds A and C through a B entity.

```
@Entity
public class B {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

}

@Entity
public class C {

    @Id
    private Integer id;  

}
```

Or if you do not want a Map you can model a entity ABC according to

```
public class AbC {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="A_ID", insertable=false, updateable=false)
    private A a;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="B_ID", insertable=false, updateable=false)
    private B b;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="C_ID", insertable=false, updateable=false)
    private C c;

    @EmbeddedId
    private A_b_C_i_D id;

    @Embeddable
    public static class A_b_C_i_D implements Serializable {

        @Column(name="A_ID", updateable=false)
        private Integer a_i_d;

        @Column(name="B_ID", updateable=false)
        private Integer b_i_d;

        @Column(name="C_ID", updateable=false)
        private Integer c_i_d;

        // getter's and setter's

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if(o == null)
                return false;

            if(!(o instanceof A_b_C_i_D))
                return false;

            A_b_C_i_D other = (A_b_C_i_D) o;
            if(!(getA_i_d().equals(other.getA_i_d()))
                return false;

            if(!(getB_i_d().equals(other.getB_i_d()))
                return false;

            if(!(getC_i_d().equals(other.getC_i_d()))
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        public int hashcode() {
            // hashcode implementation
        }

    }

}
```

regards,

Comment: Thanks. Very descriptive and helpful